# Why to put val or var in kotlin class constructors

Tags: kotlin, in-class-initialization

Just learning Kotlin In the first code down below there is the `val` keyword right in the other code there is not,
what is the different here if the `val` and `var` is omitted?

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
}

class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you omit `val` or `var` in in a constructor, then the only places that can access these parameters are initialization statements that are evaluated at construction time. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

This is useful when you want to do something with a value before storing it. In Java you would put that code a constructor body

```
class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    // directly in val / var declarations
    val firstName = firstName.capitalize()
    val lastName = lastName

    // in init blocks
    val fullName: String
    init {
        fullName = "$firstName $lastName"
    }

    // secondary constructors can only see their own parameters
    // and nothing else can access those
    constructor(fullName: String) : this("", fullName)
}
```

But it also works for [delegation using `by`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html)

```
interface Named {
    fun getName(): String
}
class Human(private val fname: String, private val lname: String) : Named {
    override fun getName() = "$fname + $lname" // functions need val since
                                               // value is resolved after construction
}
class Person2(firstName: String, lastName: String) : Named by Human(firstName, lastName)

class Person3(human: Human) : Named by human {
    constructor(firstName: String, lastName: String): this(Human(firstName, lastName))
}
```

Or in property delegation

```
class Person4(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
    val fullName: String by lazy { "$firstName $lastName" }
}
```

Note: the closure is captured at initialization time, the values are therefore still available when `lazy` evaluates eventually.

Answer (score 63):

If val or var is omitted then they won't be properties, but parameters passed to constructor. You won't be able to work with them outside of constructor.

Comment: A straight-forward explanation, the kind I was looking for.