# Kotlin constructor val vs private val

Tags: kotlin

If I have something like the following:

```kotlin
interface IRecordService {

   fun doSomething () : Record

}

@MongoRepository
interface IRecordRepository : MongoRepository<Record, String> {

}

@Service
class RecordService  (
   private val recordRepository : IRecordRepository // or just val instead of private val
) : IRecordService
{

   override fun doSomething () : Record {
      // does something
   }

}
```

Is there any difference between using `private val` in the `RecordService` constructor vs just `val`? I've seen both being used but couldn't tell if there was a recommended way or why.

Comment: Private makes it inaccessible to other classes to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't specific to Spring or Mongo; it's just core Kotlin. There are several things going on here; I'll try to unpick them.

Consider the simpler definition:

```
class MyClass(i: Int)
```

The parens specify the primary [constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors): any parameters there (such as `i`) are passed into the class, and are available during construction. So you could pass them up to the superclass constructor, use them in property initialisers, and/or in an `init` block:

```
class MyClass(i: Int) : MySuperclass(i) {
    val someProperty = i

    init {
        println("i is $i")
    }
}
```

However, they *don't* persist after the instance has been constructed — so you couldn't refer to them in methods, or from outside the class.

If you want to do that, you have to define a *property* for each parameter you want to persist. You could do that explicitly, e.g.:

```
class MyClass(i: Int) {
    val i2 = i
}
```

Here every instance of `MyClass` has a property called `i2` which is initialised to the `i` constructor parameter.

However, because this is a common pattern, Kotlin provides a shortcut. If you specify `val` or `var` in the primary constructor:

```
class MyClass(val i: Int)
```

then Kotlin creates a property with the same name as the parameter, and initialises it for you. So every instance of the above class has a property called `i` that you can refer to at any time.

By default, properties in Kotlin are `public`: you can access them from inside the class, from subclasses, from other classes in the same module, and from any other code that has a `MyClass` instance.

However, in some cases it's useful to restrict access, so you can add a [visibility modifier](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html): `internal` prevents code in other modules from seeing it, `protected` allows only subclasses to see it, and `private` makes it visible only inside the class itself.

So, to answer your question: without the `private` modifier, any code that had access to your `RecordService` would be able to access its `recordRepository` property; adding `private` prevents that, and means that only code within `RecordService` can see it.

In general, it might be a good idea to centralise all access to the `recordRepository` in the one class; then making it `private`  would ensure that no other code can muck around with it. That would make it easier to see what's going on, easier to debug, and safer to work on. (However, we obviously don't know about the rest of your program, and can't advise on whether that would be a good plan in your case.)

---

By the way, using an `I` prefix for interfaces is not a convention that's used much in Kotlin (or Java). There's often little point in having an interface with only one implementation; and if you could have multiple implementations, then better to use a simple term for the interface and then more specific terms for the implementations.  (For example: the `List` interface with `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` classes, or `Number` with `Int` and `Long`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you put `val`, it will be a constructor parameter *and* property. If you don't, it will be a constructor parameter (NOT property).
See [Why to put val or var in kotlin class constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52567108/why-to-put-val-or-var-in-kotlin-class-constructors)

Comment: Not what they were asking.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you use `val` it converts this constructor parameter to property,If you do not want to hide this property (to set it) from other classes,you can use `val`.But if you do not want your property to be changed by other classes you should use `private val` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use both `val` and `private val` in your constructor there's no problem in that, it's just that with `private` keyword your properties wont be modified or accessed by some other class, so it basically provides some data hiding. If you talking about difference in functionality inside your `RecordService` class, then no there wont be any difference.